# Azure Resource Manager - backupLongTermRetentionPolicies - Error "WeekOfYear is required to be set between 1 and 52 in order to set yearly retention."

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

We are using Azure Resource Manager templates (ARM templates) deployment scripts and would like to set different retention policies if we are in production or test.

Using export template for our current Dev SQL server gives these values:

[image]

If these values are copied to our deployment script as is:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies",
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'), '/', parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'), '/default')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'), parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "weeklyRetention": "PT0S",
        "monthlyRetention": "PT0S",
        "yearlyRetention": "PT0S",
        "weekOfYear": 0
    }
},
```

I get the following error:

> Resource
> Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies
> 'our-sql-server/our-sql-server/default' failed with message '{
> 11:14:50 -   "error": { 11:14:50 -     "code":
> "LongTermRetentionMissingWeekOfYear", 11:14:50 -     "message":
> "WeekOfYear is required to be set between 1 and 52 in order to set
> yearly retention." 11:14:50 -   } 11:14:50 - }'

The error `"WeekOfYear is required to be set between 1 and 52 in order to set yearly retention."` is in the expected responses but given that the value is there as standard it seems like a bug with `yearlyRetention` set to `PT0S`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/managedinstancelongtermretentionpolicies/createorupdate

Comment: not sure why do you think thats a problem? `As a consequence, if 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year (there is no week 00).`  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates

Comment: @4c74356b41, no problem with that but imao the default value should not be an invalid value in the first place.

Comment: ah, ic. yeah, that is probably true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by removing `monthlyRetention`, `yearlyRetention` and `weekOfYear` parameters.

Parameters:

```
"weeklyRetention": {
  "value": "P4W"
},
```

deployscript:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies",
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'), '/', parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'), '/default')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'), parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_prod_repository_name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "weeklyRetention": "[parameters('weeklyRetention')]"
    }
},
```